# Loading layer from ArcSDE for SQL Server Database using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I am use this code to load a layer from ArcSDE SQL Server database, but it only loads a table.

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("localhost","", "arcsde", "sa", "****")
uri.setDataSource('dbo','Shelter',"geom")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "Shelter", "mssql")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

I try to use the follow code,it's can load layer from SQL server,but it can be edited,why?
uri = "MSSQL:server=localhost;database=arcsde;tables=dbo.SHELTER;trusted_connection=yes"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, u"shelter", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

Comment: Please **edit the question** to specify the geometry storage format of your enterprise geodatabase feature class, and the version of ArcGIS in use.